# How to change language in runtime

Tags: android

I had read about localization here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html
But I need to switch language in my android applicartion in run time, e.g. via Spinner.

I attempted to do subj in this way

```
DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
conf.locale = new Locale(language_code.toLowerCase(),
coutry_code.toUpperCase());
res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```

but all changes apply only after restarting app
Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Well in the localization guide it automatically updated... and when I use spinners in my application it updates correctlly.. you have the spinner class set up at the bottom of your class right? or simply in the choices of your spinner, have it restart your intent like:

```
//spinner class start...
if(selected.equals("english") //given selected is a string returned by Spinner
{
   //normal spinner content you have goes here, then
   //for example, finish method, then restart with an intent
   finish()
   Intent myIntent = new Intent(main.this,main.class);
   main.this.startActivity(myIntent);
}
 //or..
if(selected.equals("french"){ // continued.. 
   refresh();
}

//given that refresh();
public void refresh(){
   finish()
   Intent myIntent = new Intent(main.this,main.class);
   main.this.startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Sam!
Maybe you can answer how to get resource string from certain locale?

Comment: I'm sorry, you're going to have to illaberate a little more.. I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you asking like, how to have multiple places to get strings from?

Comment: I have few locales - en, ru, fr, de. When in device settings selected e.g. French locale and I attempt to call getString(strId) the value returned to me would be from fr/strings.xml, but what if I want to get string from a different one, e.g. English? Does exist some way to get string like getString(strId, locale) ?